# Drupal: #weight and forms

Tags: forms, drupal

I  am writing a module in which a fieldset containing a bunch of buttons gets added to the edit/add node form using hook_form_alter.

The fieldset(the buttons) are supposed to be connected to a certain widget for a field. For example maybe the body field widget of content type 'myContentType'. I always want the fieldset and the widget of the field to be placed together in the form, preferably with the fieldset above the widget. So to achieve this I thought I would use the #weight property of the form elements.

So in hook_form_alter I set:

```
$form['buttonFieldset'][#weight] = $form['body']['#weight'] - 1;
```

Afterwards I check in the $form array and the weight of the button field did get set to a weight one smaller than the associated widget. I thought this would place it right above the textarea of the body, but this did not happen. Does anyone know why not? Or some other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your fielsdset weight to the weight of the body field and move the body field lower in the list.  So:

```
$form['buttonFieldset']['#weight'] = $form['body']['#weight'];
...
$form['body']['#weight'] = $form['body']['#weight'] + 1;
```

This works, especially if you have the title immediately above the body field as Drupal doesn't seem to like moving the title field despite changing the `#weight` for it. I haven't been able to move the `title` up in order to put something in between `title` and `body` but I can move the `body` down.